# How do you show the value assigned to an integer from a lookup table with yii?

Tags: php, yii

In my form, I created the value by populating the dropbox from values from a table.

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'status', CHtml::listData(Statusprospect::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'status'),array('prompt' => 'Select')); ?>
```

When I view the record it has a 1, as it should for status. How do I make it display the value when the record is viewed, instead of the 1.

The view file code that currently displays the field is this:

```
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->status); ?>
```

The Model does have the relationship defined:

```
    public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'status0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Statusprospect', 'status'),
    );
}
```

How would I accomplish showing the value instead of the number?

Comment: What is the output/error if any?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is for a view screen. The best approach would be to create a RELATION between your Table and the Statusprospect table. You can configure the relationship in the relations() method in your class. Then, in your view, print <?php echo $model->status_prospect->status; ?> (assuming status_prospect was the name you gave to your relationship.

Comment: Didn't seem to work, so I added more info. This minght help you better understand my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now this should work `$data->status0->status`.

Take care that $data->status0->status might not be set if $data->status can be null so make a check beforehand if that is the case. You can use

```
CHtml::encode(isset($data->status0->status) ? $data->status0->status : '-');
```